# Using Tab Navigation, bottom notch is the wrong color

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using React-Native and Expo. I'm using Tab Navigation for some screens and Stack Navigation for those I don't want to have tabs. Unfortunately, on the screens with Tab Navigation on them, the bottom notch (at least on iOS) keeps a white background. The top notch has the appropriate background color. On the Stack Navigation pages, everything is the correct color.

[image]

Here is my App.js file, after this is the screen seen in the screenshot above.

App.js

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { MotivatorSettingsProvider } from './src/context/motivatorSettingsContext';
import { DBProvider } from './src/context/dbContext';
import ActionScreen from "./src/screens/ActionScreen";
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import NewInformationScreen from "./src/screens/NewInformationScreen";
import UserSettingsScreen from "./src/screens/UserSettingsScreen";
import AnalysisScreen from './src/screens/AnalysisScreen';
import ViewUserImagesScreen from './src/screens/ViewUserImagesScreen';
import useDatabase from './src/hooks/useDatabase';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export function Root() {
  const isDBLoadingComplete = useDatabase();

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => {
          const size = 24;

          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            return <Ionicons name={'home'} size={size} color={color} />;
          } else if (route.name === 'UserSettings') {
            return <Ionicons name={'md-settings-sharp'} size={size} color={color} />;
          } else if (route.name === 'NewInformation') {
            return <Ionicons name={'ellipsis-horizontal-circle'} size={size} color={color} />;
          } else if (route.name === 'Analysis') {
            return <Ionicons name={'md-analytics'} size={size} color={color} />;
          }

        },
        tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        tabBarActiveBackgroundColor: "black",
        tabBarInactiveBackgroundColor: "black",
        tabBarStyle: {
          borderTopColor: "#CCCCCC",
        }
      })}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Analysis"
        component={AnalysisScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: "Analysis"
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="UserSettings"
        component={UserSettingsScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: "Settings"
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="NewInformation"
        component={NewInformationScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarLabel: "Information"
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Root"
          component={Root}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Action"
          component={ActionScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ViewUserImages"
          component={ViewUserImagesScreen}
          options={{
            headerShown: true,
            title: "Your Images",
            headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: "black",
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              color: "white",
            }
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
};

export default () => {
  return (
    <DBProvider>
      <App />
    </DBProvider>
  );
};
```

Analysis.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, SafeAreaView, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import HeaderComponent from '../components/HeaderComponent';

const AnalysisScreen = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <HeaderComponent showBack='true' showSettings='false' />
            <SafeAreaView style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: "black" }]} >
                <ScrollView>
                    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>Analysis Screen</Text>
                </ScrollView>
                {/* <NotificationComponent /> */}
            </SafeAreaView>
        </>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    contentContainer: {
        flex: 1,
    },
});

export default AnalysisScreen;
```

This is probably something simple but I just can't get it figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `SafeAreaView`, that is preventing your app from taking up the entire screen. Use a regular `View` instead, this will allow your `backgroundColor: "black"` styling to work on the bottom portion of your app.

Comment: I replaced all instances of SafeAreaView with View but unfortunately the issue still remains. On the Stack Navigation pages, even though they are using <SafeAreaView>, they don't have the same background color problem, they display properly with the dark background covering the entire screen.

Comment: Try changing the value of ```backgroundColor``` inside of ```tabBarStyle``` in ```App.js```.